# python operation without taking all the memories

Tags: python

I wrote simple code to simulate the lottery draw which you have to correctly pull the 6 numbers out of 49.

```
import random
x = list(range(1,50))

winning_numbers = random.sample(x,6)

def lotto(testlist):
    one_draw = random.sample(list(range(1,50)),6)
    num = len(list(set(testlist) & set(one_draw)))
    return num

iteration = 1
draw = lotto(winning_numbers)
while(draw != 5):
    draw = lotto(winning_numbers)
    iteration += 1
    print("winning number is",winning_numbers,",",draw,",",1/iteration*100,"%")
```

This will generate the output lines as

```
winning number is [26, 43, 21, 40, 28, 46] , 1 , 0.08628127696289906 %
winning number is [26, 43, 21, 40, 28, 46] , 0 , 0.08620689655172414 %
winning number is [26, 43, 21, 40, 28, 46] , 1 , 0.08613264427217916 %
winning number is [26, 43, 21, 40, 28, 46] , 2 , 0.08605851979345956 %
winning number is [26, 43, 21, 40, 28, 46] , 1 , 0.08598452278589853 %
winning number is [26, 43, 21, 40, 28, 46] , 2 , 0.0859106529209622 %
winning number is [26, 43, 21, 40, 28, 46] , 1 , 0.08583690987124463 %
winning number is [26, 43, 21, 40, 28, 46] , 4 , 0.08576329331046312 %
```

so it iterates until the correct set of numbers are sampled. When I make it iterates until the number of correctly guessed numbers are actually 6, python will quickly reaches very high memory usage like this while iterating.

[image: My task manager]

I was wondering if there is other way around to code the same function without endlessly taking more memories during iteration process?

Comment: Doesn't look like anything in that code should be endlessly consuming RAM. Have you tried expanding out the Python applications and seeing a breakdown - have you got another Python process running *which is consuming* RAM?

Comment: Looks like you running 3 Python processes. Click on the triangle to expand "Python (3)". Likely, another Python process is consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: You should print the process ID `import os;print(os.getpid()) ` and turn the column "PID" on in your Task Manger to see which Python process is running your lotto game.

Comment: No, there is no other python process that is running. the probability of getting all the 6 numbers is extremely low so it will take a quite a bit of time, meanwhile, RAM usage will keep increasing until it crashes or get the right set of numbers (haven't run it until it actually gets all 6 numbers but RAM usage will hit over 2GB at some point). I just want to know if there is another way to avoid this doing this kind of computation.

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the full code? For me it is running with  a constant memory usage of 5684K.